# violin plot in R and values in X axis

Tags: r

I created these two violin plots in R, using:

```
install.packages("vioplot")
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
vioplot::vioplot(HEL$Y,las=2,main="HEL$Y",col="deepskyblue",notch=TRUE)
vioplot::vioplot(ITA$Y,las=2,main="ITA$Y",col="aquamarine",notch=TRUE)
```

as a result I get the following. However, I don't know why in the X axis I get 1 and 2. How can I get rid of the 2?

Thanks for your help.
[image]

Comment: Please share some reproducible data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(ncp)) 
        .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)
    else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mysterious behavior is due to the use of the argument "`notch = TRUE`". Example:

```
set.seed(456)
vioplot(rnorm(10), notch = TRUE)
```

[image: Violin plot]

My interpretation is that `notch` is not an argument of `vioplot`, so the function interprets it as data to add to the graph (see the little smudge at y = 1: that's where it wants to put the new data, since `TRUE` equals 1 when it is converted into a numeric).

To confirm that an unknown argument is interpreted as data to be plotted, here is a little experiment:

```
vioplot(rnorm(10), unknown_argument = rnorm(10))
```

And the result:

[image: Other violin plot]

Answer (score 0):

This is a `ggplot2` solution in case you're interested.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Recreate similar data
HEL <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(50, 8, 3))
ITA <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(50, 9, 2))

# Join in a single dataframe and reshape to longer format
dat <- bind_rows(rename(HEL, hel_y = Y),
                 rename(ITA, ita_y = Y)) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(everything())

# Make the plots
dat |> 
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = name)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("deepskyblue", "aquamarine")) +
  theme(legend.position = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks. but how does ggplot2 work if I want to read the data from a .RData file? HEL$Y and ITA$Y are in values.RData 
in my example I first did load("VALUES.RData") and then vioplot etc...

Comment: It looks like your .RData file contains two dataframes, `HEL` and `ITA`. I used these two dataframes in the second part of my code, starting with `dat <- bind_rows(` - this should work for you as well.

Comment: Thanks Andrea. When I leave the first part of the code and start with the second, I get the following messae: Error in `pivot_longer_spec()`:
! Can't combine `COUNTRY` <character> and `XCOO` <double>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: It's difficult to give you specific help if I don't know what your data looks like. It looks like you need to change the argument in `pivot_longer` from `everything()` to just a selection of the columns that you need to reshape. Please read [this introduction to pivoting](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#longer).